# integral constraint induce a manifold on Sobolev space

Tags: differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces, compact-manifolds

given the set 
$$
M:=\{u\in H^2(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}u=m\,\} 
$$
$m\in \mathbb{R}$,
$\Omega $ is a bounded piecewise smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

also denote by $u(t)$ a map:  $u(t):(0,T)\to M$

and given a functional $E:\mathbb{R}\to M\to \mathbb{R}$ by $E[u(t)]$.

I want use the chain rule to differentiate $\frac{d}{dt}E=\nabla E\cdot u_t$,

but I am not sure that $M$ is Banach space (so I can't use Frechet derivative),

so what is the correct way of using the chain rule, namely , what is the definition of $\nabla E$ on M (parallel to Frechet derivative)?

Does M is some manifold?

thank you

Comment: Seems that $M$ is a codimension one affine subset of $H^2(\Omega)$. Why is it not a Banach manifold?

Comment: It is not closed under addition, maybe if m=0 it is indeed Banach space and then I can use the usual Frechet derivative.

Comment: But $M$ is just a translation of $M_0 = \{ u\in H^2(\Omega) : \int u = 0\}$.

Comment: Oh, I see, m is in fact the zero of M, thank you.